# How can I call a web service to insert a record into a database with jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services

I am actually not sure if a webservice would be the correct way to go or if there is a better alternative, but here is my question.  I have a dropdown with some products and I want to give the user the ability to add a new product, so when they select add new, it will pop up a dialog and when they are done it will insert the new product into a table in the database.  My UI is basically a dropdown that is just html tags and I want to use JQuery to hopefully handle the backend processing.  My webservice or alternative is asp.net.  Can JQuery do this? and does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JQuery to issue web service call. Here is a [good example](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) here. Then in your web service method, you will insert the record into the DB.

So, your web service is your bridge. JQuery itself is client-side technology.